# Lambda expressions, how to search inside an object?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm starting to love Lambda expressions but I'm struggling to pass this wall:

```
public class CompanyWithEmployees {
    public CompanyWithEmployees() { }
    public Company CompanyInfo { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

My search:

```
List<CompanyWithEmployees> companiesWithEmployees = ws.GetCompaniesWithEmployees();
CompanyWithEmployees ces = companiesWithEmployees
        .Find(x => x.Employees
        .Find(y => y.PersonID == person.PersonID));
```

So, I want to get the Object "CompanyWithEmployees"  that have that Person (Employee) that I'm looking for, but I'm getting "*Cannot implicit convert 'Person' To 'bool')*" which is correct, but if I'm not passing the Person object, how can the first Find executes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you want to check for existance, perhaps try:

```
ces = companiesWithEmployees
        .Find(x => x.Employees
        .Find(y => y.ParID == person.ParID) != null);
```

This will check for any `Person` with the same `ParID`; if you mean the same `Person` instance (reference), then `Contains` should suffice:

```
ces = companiesWithEmployees
        .Find(x => x.Employees.Contains(person));
```

Comment: The property was `ParID` when I posted ;-p

Comment: Yes it was, I had to changed it cause it's an internal name, so I changed to a public name :) I'm sorry for that, but I get the point :)

Comment: I should note that by using just `Find`, you retain the ability to use 2.0 if you need; `Any`, `First`, etc require 3.5 - which is great if you have it ;-p

Comment: I ended up using .Contains, thank you Marc.
Isn't Lambda Expression a treat or what? :-D

Comment: I'm using get; set; a lot ... so I need 3.x ;)

Comment: @balexandre - that (get;set;) is C# 3.0, which is a separate concept to the .NET version; you can use C# 3.0 even with .NET 2.0 (via multi-targetting).

Comment: @balexandre: get; set; will still work in 2.0.  The compiler still generates 2.0 valid IL.

Answer (score 7):

`Find()` returns the found object. Use `Any()` to just check whether the expression is true for any element.

```
var ces = companiesWithEmployees
    .Find(x => x.Employees
    .Any(y => y.PersonID == person.PersonID));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ces = companiesWithEmployees
    .First(x => x.Employees.Any(p=>p.PersonID == person.PersonID));
```

Comment: something as David :) you were late, no upvote for you ;-) but thank you anyway for you kindness and help.

Comment: Actually, I was faster than David, you can check it by sorting the result by oldest first ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
ces = companiesWithEmployees.Find( x => x.Employees.Find(...) );
```

`.Find` returns ***only one*** object, `x.Employees.Find(..)` returns `Person`.

`.Find` expects boolean parameter(i.e. the result of conditions), that's why there's a compiler error that says `Cannot implicit convert 'Person' To 'bool'`

`.Where` can return multiple objects, hence **can iterate through all** list.

use a combination of `.Where` and `.Any` in your case.

the following code will illustrate the difference between `.Where`, `.Find`, and `.Any`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var companiesWithEmployees = new List<CompanyWithEmployees>() {                
            new CompanyWithEmployees {                 
                CompanyInfo = new Company { CompanyName = "Buen" },
                Employees = new List<Person>()  { 
                    new Person { PersonID = 1976, PersonName = "Michael" },
                    new Person { PersonID = 1982, PersonName = "Mark" },
                    new Person { PersonID = 1985, PersonName = "Matthew" },                            
                    new Person { PersonID = 1988, PersonName = "Morris" }
                }
            },
            new CompanyWithEmployees {
                CompanyInfo = new Company { CompanyName = "Muhlach" },
                Employees = new List<Person>() {
                    new Person { PersonID = 1969, PersonName = "Aga" },
                    new Person { PersonID = 1971, PersonName = "Nino" },
                    new Person { PersonID = 1996, PersonName = "Mark" }
                }
            },
            new CompanyWithEmployees {
                CompanyInfo = new Company { CompanyName = "Eigenmann" },
                Employees = new List<Person>() {
                    new Person { PersonID = 1956, PersonName = "Michael" },                        
                    new Person { PersonID = 1999, PersonName = "Gabby" }
                }
            }
        };

        // just explicitly declared the types (instead of var) so the intent is more obvious

        IEnumerable<CompanyWithEmployees> whereAreMichaels = companiesWithEmployees
            .Where(cx => cx.Employees.Any(px => px.PersonName == "Michael"));

        string michaelsCompanies = string.Join(", ", whereAreMichaels
            .Select(cx => cx.CompanyInfo.CompanyName).ToArray());

        MessageBox.Show("Company(s) with employee Michael : " + michaelsCompanies);

        Person findAga = companiesWithEmployees
            .Find(company => company.CompanyInfo.CompanyName == "Muhlach")
            .Employees.Find(person => person.PersonName == "Aga");

        if (findAga != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Aga's ID : " + findAga.PersonID.ToString());
    }
}

class CompanyWithEmployees { 
    public Company CompanyInfo { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
class Company {
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
class Person {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't specified a legitimate Find expression for your top level Find.

I'll show it here:

```
ces = companiesWithEmployees
    .Find (x => x.Employees.Find(y => y.ParID == Person.ParID) /*condition is missing here*/);
```

So what is the condition for your initial find?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one would be

```
ces = companiesWithEmployees.FirstOrDefault(x => 
          x.Employees.Any(y => y.PersonID == person.ParID));
```

without any null check